# Need Help Combining Odds Ratio Graphs for Individuals into a Single Figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am very new to R and have been struggling to figure out how to combine the multiple Odds Ratio plots from my resource selection analyses into one figure for a manuscript. I have played around with some code and researched different ways to get ggplot to work, so I apologize if my code is very wonky or if I do not initially provide all the information needed to solve this issue.

My code works correctly in plotting individual plots, but I am struggling to combine them. This is the coding I have so far, but I am not sure if this is even where I should be starting at:

```
ggp <- ggplot(NULL, aes(df_fox1, df_fox2, df_fox3, df_fox4, df_fox5, df_fox6)) +    #
geom_point(model.glm1, col = "red") +
geom_point(model.glm2, col = "blue") +
geom_point(model.glm3, col = "green") +
geom_point(model.glm4, col = "purple") +
geom_point(model.glm5, col = "yellow") +
geom_point(model.glmg, col = "orange") +
ggp 

ggplot(ggp, aes(model.glm1, model.glm2, model.glm3, model.glm4, model.glm5, model.glm6) +      geom_col())
```

**When I run this section, I get this error:
Error in `geom_point()`:
! `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: ****

```
df <- read.csv("FoxRSF_Combo.csv", header = T, as.is = T)
df = data.frame(sp = df$id, cov = df$case)
ggplot(df_list, aes(sp, cov) + geom_col())
```

When I run this section, I get this error:
Error in `ggplot()`:
! `mapping` should be created with `aes()`.
✖ You've supplied a  object
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

```
df_list = list(model.glm1, model.glm2, model.glm3, model.glm4, model.glm5, model.glm6) 

plot_model(df_list)
```

Finally, when I run the above code, I get this error:
Error in if (fam.info$is_linear) transform <- NULL else transform <- "exp" :
argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
Could not access model information.

In totality, I need all of my singular odds ratio plots combined into one plot.

If someone could provide some insight as to whether this is even the correct code to use, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it'll be easier to answer your question. However, based on your code it appears you've tried to make `ggplot2` work for your data, which is common for new users. Instead, it's better to make your data work for `ggplot2`. By this I mean getting all your "df_fox" objects into one dataframe (assuming they have the same columns and column names): 1) add "id" and "colour_name" columns to each df_fox and assign a value e.g. `df_fox1$id <- 1` and `df_fox1$colour_name <- "red"`

Comment: (cont.) 2) Use `rbind()` to combine your df_fox objects. 3) In you plot `aes()`, use the appropriate columns for x and y, use `group = id`, and use the "colour_name" column to colour each group.

Comment: Hello Leroy, Thank you for your recommendations. I made some progress with your advice - I tried the following code and got a figure with all of the points seemingly combined into one point per variable, but what I want is six points (one for each of my foxes) for each variable. I'll attach the code below as it requires too many characters.

Comment: `df_fox1$id <- 1 
    df_fox1$colour_name <- "red"
    df_fox2$id <- 2`
(etc. through df_fox6)                                                                              
     `foxes <- rbind(df_fox1, df_fox2, df_fox3, df_fox4, df_fox5, df_fox6)
    model.glm <- glm2(case ~ s.Aspect + s.Slope + s.Elevation + s.Roads + s.Herb + s.Shrub +s.Forest +      s.Stream + s.Edge + s.VRM  , family = binomial, data = foxes, weights = w)
    plot_model(model.glm)` @LeroyTyrone

Comment: Ah, may have misunderstood your issue. Could you run `dput(df_fox1)` and add the result to your question please. Also, add the code you used to generate model.glm1 to your question as well. This will help others better understand how to create a solution. Thanks

Comment: The `dput()` results were: `"red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -18958L), class = "data.frame")` @LeroyTyrone

Comment: `df_fox1 <- df_fox1 %>% mutate(s.Aspect = scale(Aspect), s.Slope = scale(Slope), s.Elevation = scale(Elevation), s.Roads = scale(Roads), s.Herb = scale(Herb), s.Shrub = scale(Shrub), s.Forest = scale(Forest), s.Stream = scale(Stream), s.Edge = scale(Edge), s.VRM = scale(VRM))` I ran out of room, so I will add the remaining code in an additional comment. Thank you (and everyone else) for their help!

Comment: `df_fox1$w <- ifelse(df_fox1$case == 1, 1, 1e3)
df_fox1.cor.s <- df_fox1[,6:11]
pairs.panels(df_fox1.cor.s, method = "pearson", hist.col = "#00AFBB",density = T,  ellipses = T) 
model.glm1 <- glm2(case ~ s.Aspect + s.Slope + s.Elevation + s.Roads + s.Herb + s.Shrub +s.Forest + s.Stream + s.Edge + s.VRM, family = binomial, data = df_fox1, weights = w)
`